# теряется " ../ " в ссылке (html)

Tags: html, url, frontend

закинул сайт на хостинг и начались проблемы,с компа всё работает.
по ссылке выдаёт на сайте выдаёт:
Not Found
The requested URL /objects/lica/lica.html was not found on this server.
хотя в коде ссылка выглядит подобным образом

в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а не надо использовать `..` в ссылках и проблем не будет

Comment: а как обозначить выход на уровень выше в дирекции файлов?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, у вас написан неполный путь до lica.html
Пробуйте прописать полный путь до директории. 
 
Иначе ваш вопрос непонятен

Comment: у меня вторая часть поста не отображается,
"хотя в коде ссылка выглядит подобным образом
<a href="../objects/lica/lica.html">
в чём может быть проблема?"
"../" как я знаю означает выход на уровень выше в дирекции файлов